# Extracting the necessary data from JSON

Tags: arrays, ruby, json

I have the following JSON file:

```
{ 
  title: "Children's Magazine",
  labels: [
     {
       category: 1
       edition: "first"
     }
  ],
  release: "11/22/1982"

  title: "Some book",
  labels: [
     {
       category: 1
       edition: "first"
     }
  ]
  release: "11/22/1982"
}
```

How can I convert it into **Ruby array** without including the `category`, so the array would look like something like this:

```
[
      title: "Children's Magazine",
      labels: [
         {
           edition: "first"
         }
      ],
      release: "11/22/1982"

      title: "Some book",
      labels: [
         {
           edition: "first"
         }
      ]
      release: "11/22/1982"
]
```

Im having troubles with these nested JSON conversions into Ruby arrays... Thanks in advance!

Comment: where are the values for `category` coming from?

Comment: @Hamms, my bad, will be updated in a sec

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the JSON structure you are dealing with:

```
[
  { 
    "title": "Children's Magazine",
    "labels": [
       {
         "category": 1,
         "edition": "first"
       }
    ],
    "release": "11/22/1982"
  },
  {

    "title": "Some book",
    "labels": [
       {
         "category": 1,
         "edition": "first"
       }
    ]
    "release": "11/22/1982"
  }
]
```

In this case you can `require 'json'` to use the [Ruby JSON library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html). This will give you the Ruby array you want.

In order to remove the `"category"` elements, you can use [`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-each) on the array you get from `JSON::parse` and remove the `"category"` elements. The final code might look something like this

```
require 'json'

array = JSON.parse(json_string)
array.each { |book| book['labels'].delete('category') }
```